# Error:Cause: invalid stream header: C8030011 instudio 2.3.2

Tags: android

I am getting the error after my system crashed. I am getting error like

Gradle 'CuztomiseStockist' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: invalid stream header: C8030011

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464473/errorcause-invalid-stream-header-000900d9-in-android-studio-2-3-1

Comment: Please try to give more explanation while asking the question..It will easy for us to find better solution

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha android studio itself giving me that much info only .