# Getting "invalid stream header: 00000000" error when generating a apk in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

I was able to generate debug apks just fine then suddenly my pc crashed and from then, whenever i am trying to generate a apk it gives this error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin'
> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

These are some pics for reference

[image]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464473/errorcause-invalid-stream-header-000900d9-in-android-studio-2-3-1? If so, what happens when you try the proposed solutions there?